# Growth of Betti numbers in moduli spaces of complex stable curves as the number of marked points vary

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

$\newcommand{\Mgn}{\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}} \DeclareMathOperator{\nn}{\mathbb{N}} \DeclareMathOperator{\zz}{\mathbb{Z}}$Let $\Mgn$ be the Deligne−Mumford−Knudsen moduli space of stable curves of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points (over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$). Writing $b_j(X)$ for the $j$-th (rational) Betti number of a space $X$, my question is about the growth of the sequence
$$\beta(j,g)_n := b_j \left(\Mgn\right)$$
as $n$ varies, with $j$ and $g$ fixed. It is known that for every $j,g \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence $\beta(j,g)$ (with the index $n$ suppressed) has at most exponential growth, for instance by ([Tosteson, Stability in the homology of Deligne-Mumford compactifications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03894)).

Given $g \in \nn$, write
$$
Z(g) := \big\{j \in \nn : \text{ the sequence }\beta(j,g) \text{ is identically zero}\big\}
$$
$$
P(g) := \big\{j \in \nn : \text{ the sequence } \beta(j,g) \text{ grows at most polynomially}\big\}
$$
so that $Z(g) \subseteq P(g) \subseteq \nn$. The most general (perhaps ambitious) question I have is an explicit description of these sets for every $g \in \nn$. Here is what I have been able to gather:

• As every $\Mgn$ is simply-connected (see for instance [Boggi−Pikaart, Galois Covers of Moduli of Curves](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/galois-covers-of-moduli-of-curves/8E359287EFB8C1C2F98C3B14863A53F9))), we have $0 \in P(g) - Z(g)$ and $1 \in Z(g)$ for every $g \in \nn$.

• It is shown in ([Arbarello−Cornalba, Calculating cohomology groups of moduli spaces of curves via algebraic geometry](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1998__88__97_0)) that $3,5 \in Z(g)$ for every $g \in \nn$.

• It is shown in ([Bergström−Faber−Payne, Polynomial Counts and Odd Cohomology Vanishing on Moduli Spaces of Stable Curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.07759)) that $7,9 \in Z(g)$ for every $g \in \nn$.

• It follows from ([Canning−Larson−Payne, The eleventh cohomology group of $\Mgn$](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma/article/eleventh-cohomology-group-of-overline-mathcal-mgn/F091D1AEF6548CBE5296BC55D8B41955)) that $11 \in Z(g)$ for $g \neq 1$ and $11 \in P(1) - Z(1)$.

> **Q1:** Are there $j \in \nn - \{0,11\}$ with $j \in P(g) - Z(g)$ for some $g \in \nn$ ?

• The results in ([Keel, Intersection Theory of Moduli Space of Stable N-Pointed Curves of Genus Zero](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1992-330-02/S0002-9947-1992-1034665-0/)) yield the complete answer
$$P(0) - \{0\} = Z(0) = \{2k+1 : k \in \nn\} \, .$$

• The description of $H^2(\Mgn;\mathbb{Q})$ in Arbarello−Cornalba's paper cited above implies that $2 \notin P(g)$ for every $g \in \nn$.

> **Q2:** Is every positive even integer outside $P(g)$ for every $g \in \nn$ ?

I am guessing that information about the growth of the sequences $\beta(g,j)$ can be propagated via the various operadic structures (that I am not quite familiar with) between the $\Mgn$'s in order to give at least some partial answers.

Comment: One interesting consequence of my result that you cited (and work of Wiltshire-Gordon) is the following:  if $\beta(j,g)$ is bounded above by a polynomial, then it agrees with a polynomial for all $n > 0$.   (Unfortunately, I don't have an effective bound on the degree of this polynomial right now).  You can see this phenomenon in the Canning-Larson-Payne example.

Comment: (Hi Phil I think we met in the rep-stability week in 2018, Michigan :)) This is exactly how I arrived at the subject. I am actually in the process of writing up some polynomiality results arising from promoting an FI-module (with perhaps a few shifts) to an FSet-module or FI#-module. I was wondering if the 11-th cohomology is the only known nonzero case here.

Comment: I see! (I remember meeting you in 2018). If you don't get an answer to these questions here, I would be happy to discuss more with you on zoom or email.